# Can I use Ext's loader to load non-ext scripts/object dynamically?

Tags: extjs4

In my ExtJS 4.0.7 app I have some 3rd party javascripts that I need to dynamically load to render certain panel contents (some fancy charting/visualization widgets).

I run in to the age-old problem that the script doesn't finish loading before I try to use it.  I thought ExtJS might have an elegant solution for this (much like the class loader: Ext.Loader).

I've looked at both Ext.Loader and Ext.ComponentLoader, but neither seem to provide what I'm looking for.  Do I have to just "roll my own" and setup a timer to wait for a marker variable to exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've looked at both Ext.Loader and Ext.ComponentLoader, but neither
>   seem to provide what I'm looking for

Really looks like it's true. The only thing that can help you here, I think, is Loader's `injectScriptElement` method (which, however, is private):

```js
var onError = function() {
  // run this code on error
};
var onLoad = function() {
  // run this code when script is loaded
};
Ext.Loader.injectScriptElement('/path/to/file.js', onLoad, onError);
```

Seems like this method would do what you want (here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/XsW4N/1/)). But the only problem is that , ... you know, the method is marked as private.

Comment: Nice find!  Its a small enough function I may just 'borrow' it :)

Answer (score 11):

Here's an example of how it's done in [ExtJS 4.1.x](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-loadScript):

```
Ext.Loader.loadScript({
    url: '...',                    // URL of script
    scope: this,                   // scope of callbacks
    onLoad: function() {           // callback fn when script is loaded
        // ...
    },
    onError: function() {          // callback fn if load fails 
        // ...
    } 
});
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that this is an option now in 4.1, glad to see Sencha thought it was useful too.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what newest Ext.Loader.loadScript from Ext.4-1 can be used for.

See http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-loadScript

Answer (score 1):

For all you googlers out there, I ended up rolling my own by borrowing some Ext code:

```
 var injectScriptElement = function(id, url, onLoad, onError, scope) {
      var script = document.createElement('script'),
          documentHead = typeof document !== 'undefined' && (document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]),
          cleanupScriptElement = function(script) {
               script.id = id;
               script.onload = null;
               script.onreadystatechange = null;
               script.onerror = null;

               return this;
          },
          onLoadFn = function() {
              cleanupScriptElement(script);
              onLoad.call(scope);
          },
          onErrorFn = function() {
              cleanupScriptElement(script);
              onError.call(scope);
          };

      // if the script is already loaded, don't load it again
      if (document.getElementById(id) !== null) {
           onLoadFn();
           return;
      }

      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = url;
      script.onload = onLoadFn;
      script.onerror = onErrorFn;
      script.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState === 'loaded' || this.readyState === 'complete') {
              onLoadFn();
          }
      };
      documentHead.appendChild(script);
      return script;
  }


var error = function() {
    console.log('error occurred');
}

var init = function() {
    console.log('should not get run till the script is fully loaded');
}

injectScriptElement('myScriptElem', 'http://www.example.com/script.js', init, error, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source it seems to me that you could do it in a bit of a hackish way. Try using `Ext.Loader.setPath()` to map a bogus namespace to your third party javascript files, and then use `Ext.Loader.require()` to try to load them. It doesn't look like ExtJS actually checks if required class is defined in the file included.

Comment: `It doesn't look like ExtJS actually checks if required class ...`. Seems like it actualy does. In method `onFileLoaded` it would raise exception `"The following classes are not declared even if their files have been loaded ..."`